# Do Resplendent Circlet and Aversion Staff work together?

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, optimization

This seems quite a powerful combination.

**Aversion Staff:**

> **Property**
>   You gain a +2 item bonus to all defenses against attacks from enemies that are subject to effects caused by you.

**Resplendent Circlet:**

> **Property**
>   Enemies within 10 squares of you take a –2 penalty to Insight checks. Those enemies are not aware of this effect.

So the real question here is if a -2 penalty to Insight is an effect caused by me?

*For an even better combination use Skull Mask. It is not only cheaper, but the properties are actually useful.*

Comment: good question, also fair warning. Depending on how much your GM supports 4e's RAW and specificity beating generality they will either implicitly support this or say that its an abuse of the rules and too powerful and not allow it.

Comment: It is not that overpowered considering that the Circlet is quite useless, so you have to give up an actually useful Head Slot item to get this.

Comment: I agree that the opportunity cost is high and thus balances it, but some DMs are touchy about the math aspect of 4e and items letting you have higher maths because of their baggage from previous D&D editions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes**

4e defines and effect as:

> **Effect**
>
> The result of a game element’s use. The damage and conditions caused by an attack power are the power’s effects, for instance. Some powers have “Effect” entries, which contain some but not necessarily all of the powers’ effects. In an attack power, the effects of such an entry are not contingent on a hit or a miss.
>
> Published in Player's Handbook 2, page(s) 219, Rules Compendium, page(s) 311.

While the example given is primarily with attack powers, properties are always on item effects. Thus any creature within 10 of you would be effected by Resplendent Circlet. Your Aversion Staff's property would trigger of the effect of Resplendent Circlet giving you an effective +2 against any enemy within 10 of you.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

> **PHB 1, pg226**
>
> In general, magic item powers follow the same rules as other powers

Thus, since you're essentially activating a new power/effect that's available to you then counts as an effect coming from you.  And I don't see any exceptions within the descriptions of the items in question.